# interpreting coffeescript in a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb, asset-pipeline

I am adding some view specific .js code to the header of the page using `content_for` like so

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script lang="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("<%= book_chapters_path(@book) %>", function(data){

    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

now how would I switch that js code to coffescript, can I put in a code block to tell rails to convert it to javascript, or even just add "lang/coffeescript" and rails would then just handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this gem: https://github.com/markbates/coffeebeans

Comment: I did notice that, but doesn't it compile every time the view is accessed?

Comment: This gem not required to render coffee-script in partials. `coffee-rails` does it out-of-box.

Answer (score 3):

In layout:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%- javascript_tag do %>
    <%= render :partial => "cs/coffee-partial" %>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

Where `cs/coffee-partial` is a `views/cs/_coffee-partial.html.coffee`.
You can even pass local variables to `render` and output them into your coffee-partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "cs/coffee-partial", :locals => {:version => '0.1', :name => 'varName'} %>
```

And then:

```
lib =
  version: '<%= version %>'
  '<%= name %>': 'some value'
```